# Django query sets on many-2-many field

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am working on the following:

```
# models.py

class FinancialProduct(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    businesses = models.ManyToManyField(Business)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    main_client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    financial_product = models.ForeignKey(FinancialProduct)
    advisor = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)

class Business(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

# forms.py

class ItemForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,fpID,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['advisor'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='advisor')
        self.fields['business'].queryset = Business.objects.filter(financialproduct__businesses=fpID)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ('main_client', 'financial_product')

    def CustomSave(self,f,c,u):
        idb = self.save(commit=False)
        idb.financial_product = f
        idb.main_client = c
        return idb.save()
```

And I created the following data:

```
Business(1,'Company1')
Business(1,'Company2')
FinancialProduct(1,'Company1', 'Small Product')
FinancialProduct(1,'Company1,Company2', 'Large Product')
```

In the front end I get the following:

```
Select 'Small Product' > Get ('Company 1', 'Company 1', 'Company 2')
Select 'Large Product' > Get ('Company 1', 'Company 2')
```

Unfortunately I seem to be getting the data in the wrong way. What am I doing wrong with the third line of the `__init__`? Is it because it's a M2M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This absolutely fried my noodle (because all of this is highly counter intuitive) but I managed to come up with the following. I hope it helps someone:

```
self.fields['business'].queryset = Business.objects.filter(financialproduct__id=fpID.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
FinancialProduct(1,'Company1,Company2', 'Large Product')
```

You save an M2M with multiple queries. Say, like:

```
FinancialProduct(1,'Company1', 'Large Product').save()
FinancialProduct(1,'Company2', 'Large Product').save()
```